# [<telebot.types.MessageEntity object at 0x000002ECF1135580>]

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Имеется кусок кода.

```py
if message.entities != None:
     print(message.entities)
     if message.entities.type == "mention":
          if "@" in message.text:
               print(message.text.index("@"))
               mention = message.text[message.text.index("@")::]
               if " " in mention:
                    mention = mention[mention.index(" ")::]
               print(mention)
               #some code
```

суть в том, чтобы из сообщения вытащить упоминание юзера, а потом по username получить его id.
но дело в том, что message.entities представляет собой `[<telebot.types.MessageEntity object at 0x000002ECF1135580>]`, хотя должен что-то типа `'entities': [{'offset': 5, 'length': 8, 'type': 'mention'}]`
на https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity есть вот такая вещь:
[image]
Следовательно, `print(message.entities)` выдает немного не то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка дана на `MessageEntity`, а [entities](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) содержит массив таких объектов, который надо ещё распарсить (написано по той же ссылке).

Поэтому `print(message.entities)` просто выдает тип и адрес этого объекта (массива).